# Node.js cluster vs Node.js workers for multi-threaded plugin system?

Tags: node.js

I have a host application written in Rust and want to use Node.js for a plugin system. The "plugins" contain pure functions that take a value, return a value and I will run several instances (up to 6) in parallel.

I have two choices:

1. Spawn 1 - 6 Node.js child processes, and use stdin/stdout of each process to communicate.
2. Spawn 1 Node.js process and within it spawn 1 - 6 worker threads. Again, use stdin/stdout to communicate with the child Node.js process, but also include forwarding logic to pass data to/from the worker threads.

Which makes more sense? The first option is easier, but perhaps it will use more memory?

The workers approach requires data to be handled twice, perhaps the main Node.js thread may be overwhelmed with proxying communications and bottleneck the threads (it will be very chatty).

Any insights on how best to wield Node.js in this context?

Comment: I mean, don't child processes have more overhead??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each Node.js child process runs independently, it provides a high level of isolation. If one plugin crashes, it won't affect the others. While this method offers a simpler implementation and easier management, it's important to consider that the node.js child process consumes extra memory and resources. If the plugins are lightweight, the overhead may be acceptable, but it could become a concern if memory usage becomes a critical factor. Also Inter-process communication between the Rust host and Node.js processes can introduce some latency, especially if there is frequent communication. 
Using worker threads within a single Node.js process can reduce overall resource consumption compared to spawning multiple processes. Communication between the Rust host and Node.js process can be more efficient within a single process, as it avoids the overhead of inter-process communication. However, introducing communication and data forwarding logic between the primary Node.js thread and worker threads increases code complexity, requiring meticulous synchronization management and the avoidance of potential bottlenecks. Additionally, the shared memory space among worker threads poses a risk of cross-contamination, where a malfunctioning plugin causing a memory-related problem may impact other plugins.
If simplicity and isolation are top priorities, and the memory overhead is acceptable, option 1 may be a good fit.
If resource efficiency is critical, and you can manage the added complexity of communication within a single Node.js process, option 2 (worker threads) might be a better choice.
In either case, consider implementing proper error handling, monitoring, and logging to identify and address any issues that may occurs during runtime. Additionally, you may want to prototype both options and perform some benchmarks to evaluate their performance in your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you for this fantastically detailed answer. I am indeed writing benchmarks to determine what works better in my use case. Question; when compared to stdio, is there significant latency when using TCP sockets? I could have each worker thread connect to a TCP listener on the host thereby skipping forwarding logic from the host Node process and the workers.

Comment: Using TCP sockets will indeed introduce some latency compared to stdio. How significant will the latency be in your case? It is impossible to determine without prototyping and benchmarking against stdio approach.